For wrappers around syscalls that retry on EINTR, how many times does retrying make sense?
Often syscalls like write(2), read(2), close(2) et cetera fail due to being interrupted by a signal with the errno value EINTR (say the size of the terminal window changed and SIGWINCH was received), which is a transient error and ought to be retried, and code often uses wrappers around these sycalls that retry on EINTR (and often EAGAIN or ENOBUFS).
But it is possible to get stuck in the theoretical situation where code just continue infinitely looping on EINTR due to either receiving non-stop signals, or because the syscall was intercepted by a custom implementation of that syscall that just returns EINTR.
In such cases, in library code, how many times does it make sense to retry the syscall?

I've never seen anyone implement a retry limit on something like this. There's little reason to believe that the interrupts will occur repeatedly. It's not like an error accessing a remote resource, where there's a good chance the problem is permanent.

Not retrying isn't going to do anything to stop the stream of signals. /// Don't think of it as retrying, think of it as resuming the wait your blocking call was doing. It's what you would done if you hadn't received a signal.

Yes, it is "possible", but not "probable". Say if you created an interval timer (see, e.g. man 2 timer_create) with a repeating interval of a couple of nanoseconds, you could very likely run into something like you describe. Though that's more a result of program design error than something you would normally expect.

@ikegami Fair enough, but would it be apt for library code to fail after say 40-100 iterations, or continue looping forever?

would it be apt for library code to fail after say 40-100 iterations it would be apt. Just do it, don't work proactively - when you get a problem with 40 iterations, you'll do 100. There is little reason to care about it.

Again, it's not failing, it's waiting. What would read do without the signal? Wait forever. So why do you think you need to do something different if a signal comes in??? The point of EINTR is to give signal handlers a chance to run when a call would otherwise be blocked.

Never-ending flood of signals, overridden syscall to return EINTR? Not real-life scenarios. If the user deliberately takes extra steps to shoot himself in the foot, it's not your job to try to stop him from doing it. Just ignore them. Keep your code as simple as possible that does the job for those who aren't explicitly working on breaking them. (Unless you're writing a security critical component where the attacker can send infinite signals or override syscalls, but then you already lost the game a long time ago.)


For wrappers around syscalls that retry on EINTR, how many times does retrying make sense?

From zero to infinitely many.
Glibc standard library is in use in billions of devices around the world. Calling printf("Hello world\n"); will end up in the _IO_new_file_write function that looks like the following, from https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5aa2f79691ca6a40a59dfd4a2d6f7baff6917eb7/libio/fileops.c#L1176 :
ssize_t
_IO_new_file_write (FILE *f, const void *data, ssize_t n)
{
  ssize_t to_do = n;
  while (to_do > 0)
    {
      ssize_t count = (__builtin_expect (f->_flags2
                                         & _IO_FLAGS2_NOTCANCEL, 0)
               ? __write_nocancel (f->_fileno, data, to_do)
               : __write (f->_fileno, data, to_do));
      if (count < 0)
    {
      f->_flags |= _IO_ERR_SEEN;
      break;
    }
      to_do -= count;
      data = (void *) ((char *) data + count);
    }
  n -= to_do;
  if (f->_offset >= 0)
    f->_offset += n;
  return n;
}

As you can, while (to_do > 0) the function will loop infinitely many times until the data are written, ignorin any EINTR signal and not even checking for any.
Because this software is used in literally almost every single linux device around the world, it is safe to say that looping infinitely many times is completely fine.
Now, you may be working with a non-standard implementation of write. For example on an embedded device the programmer may implement his own implementation of write, like _write_r when using Newlib C standard library. If such a programmer sets errno = EINTR and returns 0 from his write function endlessly, I would say that's on him. But if you feel like you want to detect such situations, go ahead. I do not feel like there is the need to do it.
The contract of write function is just that when the number of bytes written is not equal to how many bytes you wanted to write, you should repeat the call, with shifted data and count. That's that.

Re "As you can, while (to_do > 0) the function will loop infinitely many times until the data are written, ignorin any EINTR signal and not even checking for any.", Doesn't it exit via break on receipt of EINTR or any other error?

@ikegami You're correct, this method indeed breaks out on any error. For most errors (e.g. input/output error), trying to repeat endlessly would most likely result in an endless busy-loop. EINTR is probably the only exception. I got here at this question trying to figure out if printf() restarts on an EINTR, wihch I don't know yet. The retrying logic could be at a lower level, in __write_nocancel() (I have no idea what that method does), or at a higher level, i.e. in the invoking method. I'm yet to figure out.
